# How to paint texture without affecting linked objects

Tags: texture-painting, linked-data, pbr

I’m trying to perform texture painting, but it also paints linked objects.

Steps:

1. Attach material to a cube
2. Copy cube via <kbd>Shidt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
3. Duplicate material in properties
4. Try to texture paint second cube
5. It applies changes to both

Inspite of creating new material (by duplicating) in material properties, it performs painting on all objects with the same texture.

Video example: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADheXxNQnZRXcEWEIYt-DUh7jWIzCk4u/view?usp=sharing)

Any possible solutions how to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 2nd material of the 2nd object, click this number to paint over a new unique texture.

[image]

Comment: Hello Josh! Thank you very much, it works as expected.
The trick was to make it in specific part (one of images in pbr texture) as you showed. Duplicating just material doesn't work for some reason

Comment: You're welcome. The duplicate material by default reuses the same texture datablock, so to make it use a new one you have to tell it explicitly.